Processes Getting Killed During Deep Learning Training (maybe due to High CPU Usage by 'netools'?)
My environment

OS : Ubuntu 20.04
core : 6


Hi,
I'm facing an issue where processes keep getting killed while running deep learning training in a Linux environment, as shown below.
 global_average_pooling2d (  (None, 1920)                 0         ['relu[0][0]']                
 GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)               (None, 2)                    3842      ['global_average_pooling2d[0][
                                                                    0]']                          
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 18325826 (69.91 MB)
Trainable params: 18096770 (69.03 MB)
Non-trainable params: 229056 (894.75 KB)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

Epoch 1: LearningRateScheduler setting learning rate to 0.0010000000474974513.
Epoch 1/150
Killed

I ran the command sudo dmesg | grep -E -i -B100 'killed process' to check the logs, but no results were returned.
After some research, I found it might be related to RAM OOM (Out of Memory). When I checked the CPU usage with the top command, I noticed that the 'netools' process is consuming nearly 600% of the CPU. Could this be related to the processes being killed?
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                    
2253 root      20   0 2451380   6516   4588 S 599.7   0.0 298:48.91 netools                                                    
 910 root      20   0 1948088  41556  29884 S   0.3   0.1   0:03.85 containerd                    

The CPU usage before the training process was killed is as follows:
    PID USER   PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                    
   2253 root   20   0 2451368   6536   4588 S 599.7   0.0 324:40.91 netools                                                    
  93857 admin  20   0   13.4g   1.4g 602488 R 100.3   2.3   0:19.27 python                                                     
  94219 admin  20   0   20460  14828   2500 S  21.3   0.0   0:00.64 nvidia-smi   

The training was working fine before, but one day, after an internet connection problem, the training suddenly isn't working properly.
What is the problem??
Thank you for reading
